# How do I trigger multiple queries in a single odbc statement connection in UnixODBC/MySQL?

Tags: mysql, odbc, unixodbc

I want to execute multiple queries in an ODBC DSN Connection to MySQL using UnixODBC. For example as below:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country) VALUES ('ABC Corp', 'India');
SELECT NAME, AGE FROM STUDENT;
```

I am using `SQLExecDirect()` to trigger the command and then `SQLFetch()` to fetch the resultset.

If I execute just one query it works fine.

I want the behavior to be the same as when I run queries on the SQL console, i.e., read back the result set.

Is there a way to do this? If not, is there a work-around?

Comment: I'm also looking.  If you figured it out can you answer your own question.

Comment: Sorry, Could not get any solution for this.